# How much does it cost to buy mutual funds? Where can I find about about the charges?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, fees, charges, commission

Regarding investing in mutual funds: How much does it cost to buy mutual funds?  Where can I find about about the charges?

Comment: I assume this means the commissions and not the actual price of a unit of the fund.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to ChrisH's response:  In addition to **front end load** and **back end load**, there are also fund expenses for trading, management, administration, etc.  These expenses are rolled up and reported as the fund's **Management Expense Ratio (MER)**.

Furthermore, there are also funds that are sold on a **No Load** basis, which means you don't pay either a front or back end load type of commission.  However, MERs are always present.  Funds may also pay **trailer fees** to the advisors that sell them.  These are small commission amounts paid each year.

All of these fees add up and can consume a significant portion of your expected investment return.  For instance, if the fees total 2% per annum and you expect to earn 8% per annum, then **25%** of your expected returns are going to fees. (Most people only consider the 2% and think that's *small*; it isn't, when expressed in terms of your *returns*!)

Prefer no-load funds with low MERs.  Funds with loads and higher fees don't outperform the market.  Do your own research to convince yourself of this.

Finally – you can usually look up the fees for a fund in its **simplified prospectus.**  Don't buy a fund without understanding what it invests in, how it is managed, and what fees are charged for buying, holding, and selling it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically for mutual funds the two main types are front end load and back end load.

**Front End Load**: The commission is charged up front and generally reduces the overall investment.

**Back End Load**: There is a defined period in which a sale of a unit of the fund will incur a commission fee.  The fee is usually a percentage of the unit price.  This will usually decrease over time until a holding period is reached at which time the commission becomes zero.

If you have access to a Financial Planner it's best to start by asking them how this works.  Usually it is different from fund to fund.